# Проектирование таблиц для хранения имен и фамилий различных национальностей

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, sql

Здравствуйте, нужно хранить в базе данных имена/фамилий нескольких национальностей.

Как спроектировать данную конструкцию? Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Все фамилии и  имена в одну таблицу, делать столбцы страна и тип(имя или фамилия).
2. Разнести имена и фамилии в разные таблицы.
3. Разнести страны в отдельные таблицы.
4. Вообще всё разнести в отдельные таблицы.

Стран может быть около 64, а может и больше. Фамилий/имен для каждой страны больше 100.

Сам склоняюсь к 1 варианту, так как количество записей не очень большое, а создавать много таблиц не хочется. Хочу услышать сторонние мнения. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @olegmar, не с того начинаете (по крайне мере в своем вопросе). 

Сначала обрисуйте **зачем** Вам эти данные, т.е. какие задачи (выполняя запросы к БД) будут решаться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Традиционный подход - три таблицы:

```
first_names - title:string, nation_code:string
last_names - title:string, nation_code:string
nations - code:string, title:string
```

nation_code это что-то вроде ru, tat, udm и т.д., это удобнее чем просто бездушная цифра id. А таблица nations вообще может лежать где-то в конфиге и держаться постоянно в памяти.

Менее традиционный подход - использовать нереляционные БД или key-value хранилища. Например, для Redis создаем ключ tat_first_names и как в массив добавляем туда татарские имена. Аналогично, в ключ tat_last_names добавлям татарские фамилии. Для mongodb можно использовать такие документы:

```
{tat: {nation_name: 'Татарские имена', first_names: ['имя раз', 'имя два'], last_names: ['фамилия_раз', 'фамилия_два'], udm: {nation_name: 'Удмуртские имена', first_names: [....], last_names: [....]}, ...}
```

Comment: Да, это пожалуй самое грамотное решение, спасибо! Но мне все-таки интересно, почему нельзя все закинуть в одну таблицу, чем это плохо? Ведь все равно больше, чем несколько тысяч записей в такой таблице не будет. И еще вопрос: где можно взять коды для всех стран мира? Типо ru, en  и т.п. И как вообще принято записывать код двумя символами? Я вот встречал где-то три: rus, usa, ita и т.п.

Comment: Чем хуже в одной таблице? Это просто медленнее, т.к. при выборке из нее придется добавлять еще одно условие, да и индекс будет составной. По поводу кодов посмотрите http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html

Comment: [Коды стран](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-3166-1)
А насчёт запихнуть в одну таблицу, как вы себе это вообще предсталяете? Распишите структуру такой таблицы.

Comment: title, country(ну ли метка страны), type ENUM(0, 1) (ну или по другому для обозначения что это: фамилия или имя)

Насчет составного индекса согласен, но сильно ли это актуально для небольшой таблицы?

Comment: @olegmar, что-то мне подсказывает, что имен и фамилий в мире многие-многие тысячи ;) Но даже если у вас сервер с легкостью перемалывает запросы к миллионным таблицам, лучше сразу делать "как надо". Если есть выбор одна таблица или 2-3, лучше выбрать 2-3. И я все-таки рекомендую использовать nosql базы для таких задач. Просто потому что реляционные БД здесь ни к чему.

Comment: Ладно, буду использовать три таблицы, как Вы советуете, спасибо!

Comment: @olegmar - использование нескольких таблиц, по мимо экономии места на повторах имён даёт сокращает ещё вероятность того что имя будет введено с ошибкой (например вели Эдуард, а кто-то решил что оно пишется Идуард - анализ проще делать)

Comment: Да, кстати, это тоже важно, не думал о повторах, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю, что это дурь полная. Почему? А посмотрите [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/). А вообще нужно обрисовать зачем нужна такая штука. Я вижу несколько вариантов.

1. Что-то вроде генератора ортодоксальных имен для каждой из народностей (не стран!). Ну, например, вы делаете сайт для выбора имени для малыша. В этом случае, я соглашусь, что стоит все разбить на страны (или народности) и в каждой из них сделать свой список. Из минусов - нерассмотренными окажутся не-классические имена.
2. Оптимизация хранения данных в базе данных, например, паспортов. В этом случае, следует учитывать, что существуют весьма странные имена и вполне возможно, что они в выбранный вами формат не подойдут.
3. Хранение персональных данных пользователя для идентификации. А нужно ли вообще имя? Вот вопрос. Обычно в компьютерных системах пользователя идентифицируют по паре логин-пароль, что снимает необходимость различения разных пользователей с одинаковыми именами. В РФ уникальным идентификатором личности гражданина РФ является не имя, не номер паспорта (он весьма часто меняется), а СНИЛС (номер в системе обязательного пенсионного страхования) или ИНН (уникальный номер налогоплательщика). Только вот это локальная особенность и, скажем, искать ИНН у американского гражданина странно (у них там свои системы).

Comment: Мне нужен 1 вариант, причем имя/фамилия определенной страны. В проекте(браузерная игра) генерируются объекты из разных стран, им нужны имена. Вот так.

Comment: Все, цель ясна =)

Comment: Тогда логичнее 3 таблицы.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что отношение именно `many-to-many`, поэтому и нельзя все закинуть в одну таблицу.
Ведь насколько я понял данные будут примерно такие:

```
имена:
вася,петя,вова

фамилии:
иванов,петров,сидоров
```

Соответственно хранить в одной таблице нельзя (так как тогда придется для каждой фамилии хранить вариант имени).

Так что вариант:

```
first_names - title:string, nation_code:string
last_names - title:string, nation_code:string
nations - code:string, title:string
```

наиболее логичный для реляционной бд.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы раскидал всё по разным таблицам (вариант 4): Причём имена наверное даже связывал через язык (могут же различатся в разных национальностях). В главной таблице были бы только ссылки

ID_FIRST_ NAME,ID_LAST_NAME, ID_COUNTRY

и свёл бы всё к первому варианту через вьюхи.

Comment: Но ведь если стран 100 - то 100 таблиц? Может тогда отдельную базу данных под них фигачить...

Comment: Нет, только 3 таблицы: t_country, t_first_name, t_last_name (BTW, а куда делись национальности?)

Comment: @olegmar, таблица имён, фамилий, стран, национальностей. общая таблица - ссылки на имя фамилию страну? национальность?

Comment: Как я описал вопрос национальность = страна. Извините, если не совсем корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала, нужно понять какие связи есть между этими данными, а именно:

```
 1. Many-to-many
 2. One-to-many
 3. One-to-one
```

Тогда сразу станет понятно, каким образом постоить базу данных, сколько нужно таблиц, и их структура и связи между ними.